# How to align different splits in align environment?

Tags: amsmath

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\begin{rcases}
-\kappa{GA}\gamma'_{xz}&=f(x) \\
-EI\phi''-\kappa{GA}\gamma_{xz} &= 0\\
\omega'-\phi&=\gamma_{xz}
\end{rcases}
\text{ in $\Omega$}\\
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
\begin{rcases}
\omega=0\\
\phi=0
\end{rcases}
\text{ at $x=0$}\\
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
\begin{rcases}
\omega'-\phi=0\\
\phi'=0
\end{rcases}
\text{ at $x=L$}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Above is the code to generate the equations below.
[image]

How could I align those equations with respect to the right brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` is the wrong tool; use `aligned` inside the `rcases` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{rcases}
\begin{aligned}
  -\kappa{GA}\gamma'_{xz}&=f(x) \\
  -EI\phi''-\kappa{GA}\gamma_{xz} &= 0\\
  \omega'-\phi&=\gamma_{xz}
\end{aligned}
\end{rcases}
& \text{ in $\Omega$}\\
\begin{rcases}
\begin{aligned}
\omega=0\\
\phi=0
\end{aligned}
\end{rcases}
&\text{ at $x=0$}\\
\begin{rcases}
\begin{aligned}
\omega'-\phi=0\\
\phi'=0
\end{aligned}
\end{rcases}
&\text{ at $x=L$}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Remember to never have a trailing `\\` in `align` and similar environments.

[image]